# UI-Router change active router style

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am using the minified version of UI-Router.  I have a couple of routes that I setup with UI-Router.  The links to these routes are nested inside of a Bootstrap navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Brand</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="route2" ui-sref-active="active">Route 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm using the UI-Router directives, `ui-sref-active` or `ui-sref-active-eq` to change the style of the active link.  I would like to be consistent and use one of these directives since I am using UI-Router for the routing itself.  I know how to change an element's class on click in the traditional Angular way.

I have a CSS class defined for the directive:

```
.active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

This works to a certain extent, but has some weird behaviors.  When the page first loads, the default route is selected and the red background appears behind it.  When you hover over the highlighted element or click it, then the red background disappears. I have tried adding `.active:focus, .active:hover` as CSS classes, but that didn't work.  I have also tried changing the class name to see if that would do anything, but it didn't.

This is probably useless, but I have the routes configured this way:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('App)
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,
            $urlRouterProvider) {
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/route1');

                $stateProvider
                    .state('route1', {
                        url: '/route1',
                        templateUrl: '../client/views/route1.html'
                    })
                    .state('route2', {
                        url: '/route2',
                        templateUrl: '../client/views/route2.html'
                    });
            }]);
})();
```

Why am I having these strange behaviors?

EDIT:

I created a Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YLBnxHKTzjPdTNFFZB52?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I just did and to no avail.  The background color appears when you click outside of the element after clicking the element itself.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle link? Also, you are having two states are active on the same time?

Comment: I created a plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YLBnxHKTzjPdTNFFZB52?p=preview.  And no, two states shouldn't be active at the same time.

Comment: Good! So you want the highlight element stays red but not the non-active tab? right ?

Comment: Correct.  I only want the active route's link to have a red background, and to stay red while it is active.

Comment: OK. What is the hover and focus effect on non-active tab? Red as well?

Comment: No.  The non-active tab shouldn't have a red background.  I think the way the directive works is that it only applies the `active` class to the route that has been clicked.  It doesn't apply that class to all of the routes at the same time.  I only want the active route's link to be red, which I have achieved to a certain extent... it's the weirdness that happens when you click it and hover over it that I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that cause this weird behavior is because you are using Bootstrap Design for the navigation bar. And Bootstrap has used `active` as class name for the same behavior you are using.
 You need to overwrite the css on the active class to fix this problem.
The following is the modification I made to achieve your goal:

Move `ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="route1"` to `li` Tag.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="route1"><a>Route1</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="route2"><a>Route2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Overwrite css for `active` class:

```
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
    background:red;
}
```

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwPIxKDppYfmFgaKKFek?p=preview)